# Uploaded file does not exist under form action url?

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, upload, jqueryform

I want to upload files with jquery form element. And as I guess it should be moved to under action url.(localhost/bla bla/uploads/) But I can not see anywhere. Please help me.

```
<form action="/uploads/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input id="UxFileBrowser" type="file" name="somename" size="chars" multiple="true" data-bind="visible: false, event: { change: uploadImage($element.files[0]) }">
    <button class="new-button" data-bind="button: {}, click: function () { uploadPlanList() }">Upload Plan List</button>        

                </form>
```

Comment: Submitted file will be moved to server temporary directory. To get it's name use `$_FILES['somename']` in PHP. Also, it's very complicated to upload file via JS.

Comment: What is your suggestion any plugin or somethngelse? @Justinas

Comment: You can do it in pure PHP